# Foreach to Variable Javascript / React

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, variables, foreach

i want to ask something about `how to join data` inside variable, so basicly I have data that I foreach (because i need to change that object), then I want to enter each data that I foreach into a variable, as below:

```js
const thisData = {["abcd","efgh"]}
for (let objData of thisData) {
    //lets say i need to change every data from word to number
    //I've managed to change it
    const newData = changetoNumber(objData)
}
```

then i need to save it to another variable, and now i'm stuck, can you guys help me?

```js
//this is what i need
console.log(listnewData)
//1234 5678
```

Comment: If this is React you'd be better off creating a new array using `map` than trying to mutate the existing array. It's not clear whether this data is meant to be stored in state or not.

Comment: Hey thanks @Andy for your comment, this data shouldn't store in state, i'll try your advice btw..

Comment: If you're using React then you either need to call that function directly with some data, and have it return some new data you can `map` over in your JSX, or store the result of calling that function in state, and use that to inform the render. That's, generally, how React works. You don't have to use state, but it is a good idea. It would help if you could add more React code to your question so we can help debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a "map".

So, the map method takes in a single parameter, a function which is called on each item, in the simplest case with a single parameter, the item itself like so:

```js
function f(x) {
    return x.length // for example
}

const thisdata = ["abcd", "efg"];
const newvar = thisdata.map(f);
console.log(newvar); // prints [3,2]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, but how to extract newvar from obj to var? i mean from `[3,2]` to just `3;2`

Comment: ``const [a,b] = newvar``

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map function to create output in the form of an array.

```js
const start = 96; // char code of 'a' is 97 

const thisData = ["abcd","efgh"]

const toNumber = (str) => {
  const strArr = str.split('');
  return strArr.map(s => s.charCodeAt() - start).join('');
}

console.log(thisData.map(toNumber))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your Data is not proper. It may be like This

```
let thisData = {
     numbers : ["asas" , "sasas"],
}
```

for that Solution might be like this

```
for(const i in thisData){
  thisData.numbers = thisData[i].map((x, index) => {
    if(typeof(x) == "string"){
      return index + 1;
  }
})

}
console.log(thisData);
```

And your Final output is :

```
{
  numbers: [1, 2]
}
```

You can also Try out this in my JSfiddle Playground
Link : https://jsfiddle.net/anks_patel/5tLnrm6c/